# I am changing the startDate and endDate for ISO format with the help of .toISOString() but its giving me wrong output

Tags: angularjs, timezone, momentjs

Want to change the time for add to google calender and converting time for san antonio , USA.

The values are given ( Its comes from somewhere in the function ):

```
/*

eventDetail.eventTimings.startDate:"2017-04-14"
eventDetail.eventTimings.startTime:"05:18:00"
eventDetail.eventTimings.endDate:"2017-04-14"
eventDetail.eventTimings.endTime:"17:18:00"

*/

var startDateTime = new moment(eventDetail.eventTimings.startDate + " " + startT, 'yyyy-mm-dd H:mm:ss').toISOString().replace(/-|:|\.\d\d\d/g, "");

// Now startDateTime= "20170120T111800Z"

// But it should be startDateTime=  "20170414T051800Z"

var endDateTime = new moment(eventDetail.eventTimings.endDate + " " + endT, 'yyyy-mm-dd H:mm:ss').toISOString().replace(/-|:|\.\d\d\d/g, "");

// endDateTime="20170120T231800Z"

// But it should be endDateTime=20170414T171800Z
```

**See the snapshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format tokens in moment (and most other libraries, platforms, languages, etc.) are case sensitive.

You used `yyyy-mm-dd H:mm:ss`.  You should use `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`.

Also, you should not use `toISOString` or `replace` here, but instead use Moment's `format` function.

```
var startDateTime = new moment(
                  eventDetail.eventTimings.startDate + " " + startT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
                 .format('YYYYMMDD[T]HHmmss');
```

You also need to decide whether or not you want to convert between local time and UTC or not.  In the above function, the input and output match because they are both in the same local time zone.  There is no `Z` in the output, because the output is not in UTC.

If you wanted it converted to UTC, then you would do this:

```
var startDateTime = new moment(
                  eventDetail.eventTimings.startDate + " " + startT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
                 .utc()
                 .format('YYYYMMDD[T]HHmmss[Z]');
```

Comment: Hi @Matt Johnson, Thanku so much. Its works for me.
Thanks a lot.    :)

Comment: Hi Matt, 
can you please help about that- when i am sending startDateTime and endDateTime to google calender then its working fine, But when i am sending this startDateTime and endDateTime to yahoo calender for add to calendar then its going wrong end time only, except endTime all the values are correct. Can you please help me on the same ?

Comment: Don't ask new questions via comments.  Search first, then post a new question if you must.